# MySQL Partitioning (innoDB) - Large table

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, partitioning

I have a MySQL very large database (1 billion rows) like this:

database : products("name","caracteristics")

Both columns are VARCHAR(50).

actually, it have no KEY sat, but "name" will be unique, so I think I will alter it as "name" PRIMARY_KEY. (I should have done that before.. now I need to perform a remove duplicate query before adding primary_key option I guess)

My problem is, when performing a simple query on the table, it takes ages literally.

`SELECT caracteristics WHERE name=blabla LIMIT 1;` //takes ages.

I was thinking of partitioning the existing table.

So here are the question:

- Is it a good idea to fix my performance issues?
- How can I achieve that?
- Is my idea of ALTER TABLE to set 'name' column as PRIMARY_KEY a good idea also?
- also about the duplicate query, I found this around here, am I doing it properly? (don't want to mess up my table...)

> ```
> delete a
> from products a
> left join(
> select max(name) maxname, caracteristics
> from products
> group by caracteristics) b
> on a.name = maxname and
> a.caracteristics= b.caracteristics
> where b.maxname IS NULL;
> ```

Comment: the delete will take forever too. I am preparing an answer. hmm and no, anyway this delete is not going to do what you expect

Comment: But there is a short answer: index, indexes, indexes, indexes. Don't think about partitioning (or at least not to solve THIS problem). Indexes! INDEXES! And do not try to run your `delete`! Wait for Seba's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also direct set a **PRIMARY KEY** with the **ignore** option like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `products` ADD PRIMARY KEY(name);
```

this will delete all duplicates from name.

**sample**

```
MariaDB [l]> CREATE TABLE `products` (
    ->   `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `caracteristics` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `products` (`name`, `caracteristics`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     ('val1', 'asdfasdfasdf'),
    ->     ('val2', 'asdasDasd'),
    ->     ('val3', 'aesfawfa'),
    ->     ('val1', '99999999');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]> select * from products;
+------+----------------+
| name | caracteristics |
+------+----------------+
| val1 | asdfasdfasdf   |
| val2 | asdasDasd      |
| val3 | aesfawfa       |
| val1 | 99999999       |
+------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]> ALTER IGNORE TABLE `products` ADD PRIMARY KEY(name);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]> select * from products;
+------+----------------+
| name | caracteristics |
+------+----------------+
| val1 | asdfasdfasdf   |
| val2 | asdasDasd      |
| val3 | aesfawfa       |
+------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
```

**test ADD PRIMARY KEY / INSERT IGNORE**

Here is a test between add Primary key and insert ignore into. and you can see that **add Primary key** (90 sec / 120 sec) is a little bit faster in this sample

```
MariaDB [l]> CREATE TABLE `bigtable10m` (
    ->   `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `bigtable10m`
    -> select lpad(seq,8,'0') from seq_1_to_10000000;
Query OK, 10000000 rows affected (24.24 sec)
Records: 10000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> SELECT * FROM `bigtable10m` LIMIT 10;
+----------+
| id       |
+----------+
| 00000001 |
| 00000002 |
| 00000003 |
| 00000004 |
| 00000005 |
| 00000006 |
| 00000007 |
| 00000008 |
| 00000009 |
| 00000010 |
+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> CREATE TABLE `bigtable30m` (
    ->   `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `bigtable30m` SELECT * FROM `bigtable10m`;
Query OK, 10000000 rows affected (28.49 sec)
Records: 10000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `bigtable30m` SELECT * FROM `bigtable10m`;
Query OK, 10000000 rows affected (29.01 sec)
Records: 10000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `bigtable30m` SELECT * FROM `bigtable10m`;
Query OK, 10000000 rows affected (32.98 sec)
Records: 10000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> ALTER IGNORE TABLE `bigtable30m` ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
Query OK, 30000000 rows affected (1 min 32.34 sec)
Records: 30000000  Duplicates: 20000000  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> DROP TABLE `bigtable30m`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.52 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> CREATE TABLE `bigtable30m` (
    ->   `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `bigtable30m` SELECT * FROM `bigtable10m`;
Query OK, 10000000 rows affected (37.29 sec)
Records: 10000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `bigtable30m` SELECT * FROM `bigtable10m`;
Query OK, 10000000 rows affected (41.87 sec)
Records: 10000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `bigtable30m` SELECT * FROM `bigtable10m`;
Query OK, 10000000 rows affected (30.87 sec)
Records: 10000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> CREATE TABLE bigtable_unique (
    ->   `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->  PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
MariaDB [l]> INSERT IGNORE bigtable_unique SELECT * FROM `bigtable30m`;
Query OK, 10000000 rows affected, 65535 warnings (1 min 57.99 sec)
Records: 30000000  Duplicates: 20000000  Warnings: 20000000

MariaDB [l]>
```

Comment: excellent! adding ALTER might be faster than duplicating all the datas i guess! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @user3916429 actually I'm wondering. Altering the table will force the engine to prune records. My gut feelings are telling me it's going to be slower than recreating the table from scratch - but please give feedback

Comment: @Sebas -in my tests it was always quicker to add a Primary key or a composite unique key. In my case i have change a table with 25.000.000 row and 3 columns 2 ints and 1 varchar(100). If you put the rows in a new table, MySQL must by often allocate disc space. if you add the key MySQL will NOT freeing the Tablespace.

Comment: @BerndBuffen quicker than what? I think adding the index directly is quite fast too. But my concern is the `ignore` part of it that is supposed to delete the duplicates. How can that go faster than doing a manual delete?

Comment: @Sebas - i have add a little test in my answer with 30000000 rows to see which case (add primary / insert ignore) is faster.

Comment: Note: "As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error." [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: @Paul Spiegel  - There is nothing in the documentation **ALTER [IGNORE] TABLE tbl_name
    [alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]
    [partition_options]** see MySQL 5.7 : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: @BerndBuffen look under **Primary Keys and Indexes** - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-index.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel - ups, sorry !!, your comment is 100% correct. I have only tested with MariaDB. Manual **As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.** Thanks for ths info

Answer (score 3):

I think partitionning is not the way you should go for this particular problem. How would you partition? On what criteria?

I think your main concern is architectural and should be fixed prior to anything else: unique records are not unique.

Because of the volumetry I think any solution will take a while to execute. But my bet is that this one is the fastest:

```
CREATE TABLE products_unique (
 name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 characteristics VARCHAR(50),
 PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO products_unique SELECT * FROM products;

RENAME TABLE products TO products_backup;
RENAME TABLE products_unique TO products;
```

Duplicates will be evinced arbitrarily, but I think it is what you are looking for anyway.
If it takes too long, you should try running it overnight... I just hope the transaction buffer does not explode on you in which case we'd have to work on some stored procedure to separate the inserts in batches.

Comment: thank you for your time. I will give it a try as quick as possible. and come back with the news.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a good idea to fix performance issues. That is the correct answer always when you have performance issues serious-enough to be wondering about performance fixes.

You can achieve that by altering the `table` and making `name` a `primary key`, as you have already realized.

Your query should not be necessary. You should create a temporary `table` instead where you would `insert` the values you deem necessary. Let's suppose the name of that table is `mytemptable`. Then:

```
insert into mytemptable(name, characteristics)
select name, characteristics
from products
where not exists (select 1
                  from mytemptable t
                  where products.name = t.name);
```

Then remove your records from `products` using

```
delete from products;
```

then `alter products`, make sure it has `name` as a `primary key` and then

```
insert into products(name, characteristics)
select name, characteristics
from mytemptable;
```

and finally `drop` your temporary table.

As about your query:

Since you remove records, `max(name)` will be equal to all other `name`s in your group if you have a single possible `name` associated to a given `characteristics` value, which is pretty safe to assume.. So, if you have a possible `characteristics` value matching a single `name`, you will remove all instances of that `name`, so yes, your query will mess your data.

Comment: You can't select from `mytemptable` while you are inserting into it.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel "The target table of the INSERT statement may appear in the FROM clause of the SELECT part of the query. (This was not possible in some older versions of MySQL.) However, you cannot insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery. " Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Please read the point from your link to the end: "When selecting from and inserting into a table at the same time, MySQL creates a temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then inserts those rows into the target table." That means that your subquery is always selecting from an empty table. Thus no duplicates will ever be found, and you will just copy the table. However if you use the "TEMPORARY" keyword to create `mytemptable` - the query won't work at all "because TEMPORARY tables cannot be referred to twice in the same statement".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks for pointing that out. Added alias to the subquery.

Comment: Sorry - that doesn't change anything. You would still copy all duplicates.